# How can I parse HTTP headers using ktor

Tags: ktor

I'm using ktor 1.5.3 HTTP client and wondering how can I deserialize HTTP response headers into a list of [LinkHeader](https://api.ktor.io/1.5.3/io.ktor.http/-link-header/index.html) values. I have the following value in my code:

```
response.headers.getAll("Link")
```

which is a list of strings, and I want to get a value of type

```
List<LinkHeader>
```

UPDATED:

The details of my use-case:

I have a backend that uses the following response headers to manage pagination:

```
Link: <https://hostname/v2/issues?orderBy=updated&orderAsc=false&perPage=15>; rel="first"
Link: <https://hostname/v2/issues?orderBy=updated&orderAsc=false&page=2&perPage=15>; rel="prev"
Link: <https://hostname/v2/issues?orderBy=updated&orderAsc=false&page=4&perPage=15>; rel="next"
Link: <https://hostname/v2/issues?orderBy=updated&orderAsc=false&page=116922&perPage=15>; rel="last"
```

I just have to parse them to understand where is the last page

Comment: There is no functionality in Ktor to parse Link Header Field. Could you please describe your use case?

Comment: Updated with the use-case details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no accurate solution from Ktor, I've implemented a workaround from [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-do-you-need-another-http-client-2eda5f5efc7a). The same do-while loop worked in my case as well. It makes a redundant API call for an empty last page but works.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not such functionality in Ktor right now, I've created this [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-2578) to address your problem. As a workaround, you can use regular expressions for your particular case to parse headers' values:

```
data class Link(val url: Url, val rel: String)

fun parse(value: String): Link {
    val matches = Regex("""<(.+?)>;\s*rel="(.+?)"""").matchEntire(value) ?: throw Exception("Cannot parse Link header value $value")
    val (_, urlString, rel) = (matches.groupValues)
    return Link(URLBuilder(urlString).build(), rel)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just found another use-case in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203635/how-can-i-parse-http-headers-using-ktor), added to your ticket